# 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect my xamarin mobile app to mysql but it always throws this exception.
I have installed the MySQL Connector/NET through Package Manager Console window in visual studio Install-Package MySql.Data.
This error shows up after running successfully the project on line `connection.open()`.

Can someone explain to me the reason or help me solve it.

here's my code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace tpExam

{

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class login : ContentPage
    {
       
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ShowToast(string message)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IToastNotification>().Show(message);
        }
            private void Login(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=tpexam;Uid=root;Pwd=;");
            string username = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtpassword.Text;

            using(connection)
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                string query= $"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='{username}' AND password='{password}'";
               using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,connection))
                {
                    using(MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // A match was found, so check whether the user is an admin or not
                            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ShowToast("Invalid username or password");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
  
        }
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterPage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Catch the exception and you will know what happened!

Comment: you need to look at the properties of the exception object - namely the InnerException - to get more detail

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+mysql+replication+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: as u can see in the code i did catch the exception and I got a more specified error which is MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager threw an exception I don't know how to solve it

Comment: see the google link I posted - this has been discussed many times